# Getting a "WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies error when deploying a class injected with an interface"

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss6.x, jboss-arquillian

I'm doing some unit tests using Arquillian on JUnit4 and Jboss6. There is a facade(SomeFacadeclass) that has the "SomeClass"(which is an interface) injected to it. When Arquillian deploys the test.war for testing the above deployment error pops up.
What should i do to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you don't have an implementation of `SomeClass` in your bean archives

Comment: I do have the implementation class and it is included in the bean archive. But that implementation class have some external dependencies. But those dependencies are included in the pom.xml. Which is sufficient if it's any other scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Everything was solved. I added the implementation class to the @Deployment archive and some other bunch of dependent classes things work fine now.